# UTF-8 in PHP File loaded by JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, utf-8, load

So i have some problem with UFT-8 in my project, everything else works fine with UTF-8.
This is what i got so far.

***HEAD in my normal HTML document***

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  ...
</head>
```

***JQuery*** in my normal HTML File.

```
function showFiles(){
    setTimeout("$('#pageContent').load('read.php"', function(){ $('#loaderImage').hide(); });",1000);
     }
```

In this PHP file i connect to the database and SELECT data.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tabke WHERE id = ?";
```

Then i use PHP while and echo the outputs.
Everything works fine only the UTF-8 didn't work.

```
Schneider Stra�e
```

Comment: And did you use a real editor and save the files as UTF8 as well, and set the database up with UTF8 etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save your php files as UTF-8 also. And you can set your db connection charset to UTF-8 like;

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "test");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

**Edit:**

If you are using PDO, you can use following;

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:$connstr",  $user, $password);
$dbh->exec("set names utf8");
```

Comment: Thx for your help. I use PDO so i add this to my connection and now it works $dbh->exec("set names utf8");. You show me the right way :)